# Have scientists tried to communicate with Sperm whales?

Tags: zoology, mammals, language

I see lots of passive studies of sperm whale click "language", usually focused on fingerprinting to identify groups and individuals. There's application of deep learning, and all sorts of advanced analysis. However, I haven't found any examples of scientists actively producing their own clicks and trying to elicit responses from whales. It seems to me that successful interactions would push our understanding of the clicks forwards much faster with a bit of a debug/test cycle.

Have studies like that ever been done? If so, can I please have links/references to the papers? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

There has been a study / rescue attempt of a group of male sperm whales a few decades ago, where female sperm whale codas (a type of rhythmic communication clicks) where played from an underwater transducer in order to entice the males and lure them from an area of confined waters and into deeper water.

According to this study<sup>1</sup>, the playback was not successful in terms of getting the whales out to deeper water, but on one occasion, one of the sperm whales made a close approach to the playback sound source. A variety of sounds were produced by the sperm whales, but no codas were recorded.

**References**:

1. Goold, J. (1999). Behavioural and acoustic observations of sperm whales in Scapa Flow, Orkney Islands. Journal of the Marine Biological Association of the United Kingdom, 79(3), 541-550. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0025315498000666

Answer (score 3):

You're right that there have been few playback studies assessing the response of sperm whales to sperm whale clicks. A couple of studies have shown a response (reduced foraging, returning to surface[1,2]) when killer whale vocalizations are played in the presence of sperm whales.

As an acoustician focused on odontocete echolocation clicks, I field a lot of questions about communicating with whales and when we're going to "get there" or "figure out what they're saying". Based on the title of your question, I'm not sure whether you envision the end goal of playback experiments to be getting us to the level where we could communicate specific messages to the whales themselves. If that *is* what you mean though, I think we're probably a long way off from that, and I'm not sure whether or not it's possible. It is not a guarantee that the way we use language and the way sperm whales using vocalizations are compatible enough for us to truly communicate.

If you mean communicate more in the context of understanding what types of clicks mean by playing them at the whales and observing their response, i.e., when we play clicks of type A, the animals always come to the surface, so clicks of type A must be some sort of surfacing cue, that's also very complex. For one thing, to draw conclusions you'd likely have to conduct experiments in a wide variety of locations/different groupings of animals, which gets expensive fast. Additionally, as animals are difficult to observe at sea in most cases, you have to factor in the added expense of equipment such as satellite tags that would be required to understand the animal's response to the sound, as you likely couldn't rely on simple visual observation. I'm not saying these efforts wouldn't be feasible, but to my knowledge these are some of the reasons why they may not be more common.

References:

[1] Curé, Charlotte, et al. "Responses of male sperm whales (Physeter macrocephalus) to killer whale sounds: implications for anti-predator strategies." Scientific Reports 3.1 (2013): 1-7.

[2] Isojunno, Saana, et al. "Sperm whales reduce foraging effort during exposure to 1–2 kH z sonar and killer whale sounds." Ecological Applications 26.1 (2016): 77-93.

Answer (score 0):

Project CETI (Cetacean Translation Initiative) is designed precisely to understand sperm whale vocalizations. https://www.projectceti.org/

Check out recent talks by Ellen Garland and Shane Gero about Project CETI with the SETI institute. Note - SETI is trying to find intelligent life in the universe, while CETI is focused on whales here on earth.

https://www.seti.org/event/seti-talks-whales-their-song-their-culture-another-intelligence-earth